# ASP.Net Core Web API with Entity Framework is there any benefit to using stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I have an SQL Server database that I am accessing with an ASP.Net Core Web API using Entity Framework. Here are 2 examples of the same query with 1 using the default query method and the second using a stored procedure.

#### Default Web API Query

```
     // GET: api/Players
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Player>>> GetPlayers()
        {
            return await _context.Players.ToListAsync();
        }
```

#### Using Stored Procedure

```
  // GET: api/Players
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Player>>> GetPlayersProc()
        {
            string storedProc = "exec GetAllPlayers";
            return await _context.Players.FromSqlRaw(storedProc).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Both of these return the exact same list of players.

My question is what are the benefits to using 1 approach over the other? Is using a stored procedure faster or more secure in any way? What are the pros and cons to both methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF provides strongly typed access to the db, so you get compile time checking of each of your queries. This comes at a minor cost to performance.

When you use stored procs there is a disconnect between the EF structures and the query, if your stored procs is incorrect, then you may not know until runtime. But yes you can increase performance with SPs, but it comes at a cost to maintenance effort.

Generally SPs are reserved in EF projects for scenarios where the SPs were pre-existing or you have some need of Uber performance or are doing something complicated that the SQL engine has optimised support for but is hard to express in C#.

SPs are also used a lot where a separate team of DBAs manage the database and access to it and your application code needs to conform to their control.

SPs are an often an unnecessary abstraction layer in EF projects, especially if you are using the code-first paradigm and are managing the schema in your solution as well.

Don't try to pre-optimise your application until you can justify it. Save the SPs for special occasions.

Comment: This is very very helpful and I am indeed using the code first approach. Let me ask you this then. A book I was using a while back was using Dapper instead of EF. I am not super familiar with Dapper, but are there any benefits to using SP's with Dapper instead of EF?

Comment: It doesn't matter what ORM you are using, the arguments are the same. The main issue is that with SPs you need to maintain C# code _AND_ SQL code, the compiler can only inform you of issues on the C# side, you need to setup proper regression testing in an environment that uses SPs. If you have a small dev team, be practical and only use SPs when you absolutely must. For a very large team, you or your DBA might enjoy the control you can get from SPs, but its a management overheap that I find often out weighs performance gains for simple CRUD commands that only take <10ms to exectute anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SPs **can do a lot more** besides returning a dataset result, which *- if you need it -* could be considered an advantage.
In this simple case there probably is no such advantage, on the contrary: you spent time creating an SP that contains SQL code that is probably very similar to what EF would have generated on the fly. And every time your model is updated, you have to make sure that all SPs are still correct for it.

Perhaps more important, SPs can be given **access rights to query tables while such rights might be locked down for plain queries**, meaning that if someone (employee or hacker) has access to a database that has such restrictions applied, then they can't run queries at will, they can only execute the available SPs. This only applies if you and/or the DBA think that such security is needed and is worth spending time and effort doing it. You'd be required to write a dedicated SP for every query scenario, keep them up-to-date with model changes, and deploy those to the server at every release. The advantages (better security) need to be weighed against the extra effort.

Comment: I have a follow up question then. Right now I usually have to make a service account to access the database because individual employees do not have access. If I was using stored procedures can I bypass using a service account? (I hope this question makes sense and I am understanding you correctly).

Comment: It depends on the situation. If you are OK with users being able to run any SP, then you could leave out the service account. But if you are so security minded then a double barrel approach (service account can run SPs, normal users can do nothing) is probably the best.